# Typescript - generic type becomes unkown

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator function but I can't seem to get the types right.
The decorator returns a function that retries a function and returns a Result which contains a value or an error.

For the retry I'm using the package `ts-retry-promise`, and more specifically, the following function:

```
function retryDecorator<T, F extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>>(func: F, config?: Partial<RetryConfig<T>>): (...funcArgs: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>;
```

This is my first attempt:

```
export function retryWithResultDecorator<T, F extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>>(fn: F, maxAttempts: number): (...fnArgs: Parameters<F>) => Promise<Result<T, Error>> {
    return async (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
        const fnWithRetries = retryDecorator(fn, { retries: maxAttempts });
        const safeFnWithRetries: ResultAsync<T, Error> = ResultAsync.fromPromise(
            fnWithRetries(...args),
            () => new Error()
        );
        const res = await safeFnWithRetries
        return res;
    }
}

async function foo(a: string): Promise<string> {
    return a;
}

const bar = retryWithResultDecorator(foo, 5) // bar is of type: (a: string) => Promise<Result<unknown, Error>>
```

Second attempt:

```
export function retryWithResultDecorator2<F extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(fn: F, maxAttempts: number): (...fnArgs: Parameters<F>) => Promise<Result<ReturnType<F>, Error>> {
    return async (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
        const fnWithRetries = retryDecorator(fn, { retries: maxAttempts });
        const safeFnWithRetries: ResultAsync<ReturnType<F>, Error> = ResultAsync.fromPromise(
            fnWithRetries(...args),
            () => new Error()
        );
        const res = await safeFnWithRetries
        return res;
    }
}

async function foo(a: string): Promise<string> {
    return a;
}

const bar = retryWithResultDecorator2(foo, 5) // bar is of type (a: string) => Promise<Result<Promise<string>, Error>>
```

The desired return type is: `Promise<Result<T, Error>>`

I understand why the two things doesn't work, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Edit:

Here's a link to CodeSandBox with the dependencies:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-6pr478?file=/src/index.ts

Thanks :)

Comment: I think we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here. When I tried to make one for you I get some missing types which prevents me from even starting on this. See: https://tsplay.dev/mp8Yxm

Comment: @AlexWayne I have added a link

Comment: You first try `retryWithResultDecorator` seems to do what you want already. If use that `foo` and `bar` from that first example, then `bar` has a type of `(a: string) => Promise<Result<Promise<string>, Error>>` which is what you want I think? It's get `string` and no `unknown`s, despite what you claim that type is. Proof: https://tsplay.dev/m334Em. And if I edit your sandbox, I get the same result. What about that isn't working for you? What is your exacted result here?

Comment: @AlexWayne my desired return type of the function is `Promise<Result<T, Error>>` which for the specific example is `Promise<Result<string, Error>>`, but the first attempt returns: `Promise<Result<Promise<string, Error>>>`, which is extra Promise in the Result object.